# Creating Azure DEV TEST environment, creates overlapping address space

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-virtual-network

Created a TEST DEV LAB type resource and Azure then automatically creates a virtual network which overlaps the company network. Which I can't seem to change.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The address space '10.0.0.0/20' overlaps with '10.0.0.0/16' in virtual
>   network 'VirtualNetworkCompany'.

It is just a warning message. This reminds that if you want to connect to other VNets like "VirtualNetworkCompany" on your side, you should avoid IP address range overlaps with these IP address range in every connected VNets and recreate your VNet to use a different range such as 10.10.0.0/16. If you do not connect the two VNets. You can keep it, it will not impact on your test lab environment.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I needed to add an additional virtual network to Dev Test virtual network, change subnet address according and then remove default virtual network ip address. Then the warning went away.

Comment: Yes, the warning means that you can not use the IP address range which overlaps with other VNet, you need to change to another Ip address range. If my reply is helpful, suggest checkmark under "Answer".